# Unable to customize Bulma Framework with node-sass

Tags: css, npm, sass, bulma, node-sass

I am learning Sass and trying to customize the Bulma CSS framework. I am trying to make it purple but it isn't working.

I have run npm init and installed Bulma and node-sass.

**My sass file**: -

```
@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma";

$purple: #8A4D76;
$primary: $purple;

body {
  background: aquamarine;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**The script part of the package.json file: -**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "sass": "node-sass scss/ -o dist/css/"
  }
```

I have created a button on which I have given is-primary class. I am getting the default Bulma green color but I am not getting the customized purple color. How should  I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default Bulma styling appears then it‘s probably not related to the script part of your `package.json` file but rather to the sass file.

It doesn‘t work because you have imported Bulma *before* customizing the sass variables.

What you should do is set `$purple` and `$primary` and then your `@import` like this:

```
// Set your variables
$purple: #8A4D76;
$primary: $purple;

// Import bulma
@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma";

// This is classic CSS not related to bulma, you can place it where your want
body {
  background: aquamarine;
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can take a look at [this example scss file from the documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/#6-add-your-own-bulma-styles).

Also if you want to use [Bulma extensions](https://bulma.io/extensions/), you need to import them **after** Bulma itself in your scss file.

So the order in your scss file should be:

1. Customizing sass variables
2. Importing Bulma
3. Importing Bulma extensions